# How to get the schema of a JSON object and output to string including types

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Given a browser debugger output of root.value with two properties in javascript

```
root.value
__proto__: {...}
firstname: "my name"
age: 25
```

I want to parse it to a JSON string including the type like below

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "title": "Basic Info",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
       "firstName": {
           "type": "string"
         },
         "age": {
           "type": "number"
     }
   }
 }
```

Does any one know how to do that in javascript or any framework I can use to achieve such?

Note: I did not created the JSON myself it's an output of another framework. So the types of the fields are unknown until runtime.

```
 JSON.stringify(root.value);
```

with only return

```
{
   {
       "firstname":" my name"
   },
   {
        "age": 25
   }   
 }
```

Comment: I edited the final output I needed. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can itertate through the object properties and combine the required object.

```js
var o = { 
  d: 15,
  s: "qwe",
  b: true,
  q: {}
};

var result = [];
for (var property in o)
{
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(property)) continue;
  
    var resultItem = {
        type: typeof(o[property])
    };
    resultItem[property] = o[property];
          
    result.push(resultItem);
}

var textResult = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2); // That's what you are looking for

document.write("<pre>" + textResult + "</pre>");
```

Note that the most outer braces are `[]` because the expected result is an **array of objects**. The JSON that you have provided in your question is invalid as long as your objects have no name.

Also, note that this script will not process inner objects recursively - you can do this yourself.

Comment: Looks like this is the output I am looking for. Is there a simple method to do this? If none I can accept  this.

Comment: @agentpx I am pretty sure that there is no such method in vanilla JavaScript :) However, such methods can, probably, exist in JS frameworks.

Comment: Ok I can deal with the braces and object name. Answer accepted.

Comment: how can I output the result without needing for a name or removing the [] braces. thanks.

Comment: never mind. you are right the output in my question is an invalid JSON. I tweaked your code to suite my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following function.

```
function getSchema(id, obj) {

  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    var  retObj = getSchema(id, obj[0]);
    delete retObj.title;
    return {
      'title': id,
      'type': 'array',
      'items': retObj
    };
  } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    var retObj = {
      'title': id,
      'type': 'object'
    };
    retObj.properties = {};
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        retObj.properties[prop] = getSchema(prop, obj[prop]);
        delete retObj.properties[prop].title;
      }
    }

    return retObj;
  } else {
    return {
      'title': id,
      'type': typeof obj
    };
  }
}
```

You can invoke it as below

```
getSchema('My object', myObj)
```

Comment: Great nice function. :D